# Concat string to a json array attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following json array:

```
[
  {
    id: 23,
    type: 'ferrari'
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    type: 'volvo'
  }
]
```

I'm looking for the easiest way to change all the type's attribute value concatenating a string.
The expected response is:

```
[
  {
    id: 23,
    type: 'car.ferrari'
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    type: 'car.volvo'
  }
]
```

Comment: That's not JSON

Comment: What have you tried to get to your expected result? SO isn't a free Fiverr :)

Comment: Nothing! I'm a java developer doing js stuff :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map over them and return a modified object:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 23,
    type: 'ferrari'
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    type: 'volvo'
  }
];

const newArr = arr.map(o => ({ ...o, type: `car.${o.type}` }));

console.log(newArr);
```

Or iterate and mutate:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 23,
    type: 'ferrari'
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    type: 'volvo'
  }
];

arr.forEach(o => { o.type = `car.${o.type}` });

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest

```
arr = arr.map(a=>{a.type='car.'+a.type;return a})
```

Comment: explain with context why this works. (End of Low-Quality Review).